# How do I get all the bottom types in an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

This is sister question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533831/how-do-i-get-all-the-base-types-in-an-assembly)

If I have an instance of

```
System.Reflection.Assembly
```

and I have the following model:

```
class Person {}
class Student : Person {}
class Freshman : Student {}
class Employee : Person {}
class PersonList : ArrayList {}
class StudentList : PersonList {}
```

How can I enumerate the assembly's types to get a reference to Employee, Freshman, and StudentList?

I'd like to be able to enumerate all the bottom types for any given assembly like the example above.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want to find all the types which no other type in the assembly derives from, right?

(Refactored for readability.)

```
var allTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
var baseTypes = allTypes.Select(type => type.BaseType);
var bottomTypes = allTypes.Except(baseTypes);
```

(Let me know if you want a .NET 2.0 version. It'll be a bit more painful.)